# How to create a Database Monad Stack in Happstack?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, happstack

I want to create a Happstack application with lots of access to a database. I think that a Monad Stack with IO at the bottom and a Database Write-like monad on top (with log writer in the middle) will work to have a clear functions in each access, example:

```
itemsRequest :: ServerConfig -> ServerPart Response
itemsRequest cf = dir "items" $ do
  methodM [GET,HEAD]
  liftIO $ noticeM (scLogger cf) "sended job list"

  items <- runDBMonad (scDBConnString cf) $ getItemLists

  case items of
    (Right xs) -> ok $ toResponse $ show xs
    (Left err) -> internalServerError $ toResponse $ show err
```

With:

```
getItemList :: MyDBMonad (Error [Item])
getItemList = do
  -- etc...
```

But I have little knowledge of Monad and Monad Transformers (I see this question as an exercise to learn about it), and I have no idea how to begin the creation of Database Monad, how to lift the IO from happstack to the Database Stack,...etc.

Comment: I tried using 'unsafePerformIO' to do IO in it. as the Happstack uses a purely combination, maybe it's your only way to do IO.

Comment: @Wu Xingbo, It's possible to do IO on happstack with liftIO, but I don't know who to pass to another monad stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely want to use 'ReaderT':

```
type MyMonad a = ReaderT DbHandle ServerPart a
```

The `Reader` monad transformer makes a single value accessible using the `ask` function - in this case, the value we want everyone to get at is the database connection.

Here, `DbHandle` is some connection to your database.

Because 'ReaderT' is already an instance of all of the happstack-server type-classes all normal happstack-server functions will work in this monad.

You probably also want some sort of helper to open and close the database connection:

```
runMyMonad :: String -> MyMonad a -> ServerPart a
runMyMonad connectionString m = do
   db <- liftIO $ connect_to_your_db connectionString
   result <- runReaderT m db
   liftIO $ close_your_db_connection db
```

(It might be better to use a function like 'bracket' here, but I don't know that there is such an operation for the ServerPart monad)

I don't know how you want to do logging - how do you plan to interact with your log-file? Something like:

```
type MyMonad a = ReaderT (DbHandle, LogHandle) ServerPart a
```

and then:

```
askDb :: MyMonad DbHandle
askDb = fst <$> ask

askLogger :: MyMonad LogHandle
askLogger = snd <$> ask
```

might be enough. You could then build on those primitives to make higher-level functions. You would also need to change `runMyMonad` to be passed in a `LogHandle`, whatever that is.

Once you get more than two things you want access to it pays to have a proper record type instead of a tuple.

Comment: Side topic: for connection pooling there is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pool. That may be more than you need, though.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some minimal working code compiled from snippets above for confused newbies like me.

You put stuff into `AppConfig` type and grab it with `ask` inside your response makers.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Happstack.Server
import Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

myApp :: AppMonad Response
myApp = do
    -- access app config. look mom, no lift!
    test <- ask

    -- try some happstack funs. no lift either.
    rq <- askRq
    bs <- lookBS "lol"

    -- test IO please ignore
    liftIO . print $ test
    liftIO . print $ rq
    liftIO . print $ bs

    -- bye
    ok $ toResponse ("Oh, hi!" :: C.ByteString)

-- Put your stuff here.
data AppConfig = AppConfig { appSpam :: C.ByteString
                           , appEggs :: [C.ByteString] } deriving (Eq, Show)
config = AppConfig "THIS. IS. SPAAAAAM!!1" []

type AppMonad = ReaderT AppConfig (ServerPartT IO)

main = simpleHTTP (nullConf {port=8001}) $ runReaderT myApp config {appEggs=["red", "gold", "green"]}
```